# More than two glossing lines linguex

Tags: linguistics, linguex

I am new here. I need some help with the use of `linguex`. I want to be able to make more than two even up to four glossing lines with that package like in the pdf here. But I fail to do it. Would anyone help me?

[image]

This is the code sample:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Doulos SIL}
\usepackage{linguex}
%\geometry{a4paper, left=15mm, right=15mm, top=20mm,}
\begin{document}


\exg. ì náà fɔ́ à yèn kó ǹ báb básè  \\
 ì ni-à fɔ́ à yen kó ǹ báti bási-È  \\
 2SG SBJV-3SG say 3SG BNF QU 1SG PFV.OF medicine-ART  \\
 PRO N V PRO POST QU PRO ASP N  \\
\glt ‘Youi should tell him: Ii have found the medicine.’\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Although `linguex` uses the same glossing macros as `gb4e` the solution given in this question [Align glosses in more than one language with gb4e](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/156066) might be adaptable to  `linguex` as well with some work. If it's possible for you to use `gb4e` instead of `linguex` I would recommend doing so.  But if you are going to be working with these types of glosses a lot, you may want to consider switching to ExPex.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But isn't there any way to redefine the linguex glossing command so that we have multiple glossing lines?

Comment: As I said, yes, the solution I gave for `gb4e` can likely be adapted since `linguex` uses the same basic glossing mechanism as `gb4e`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. But is it possible for you to make your code to be very simple, like to be in a package so that I just need to load it in the preamble instead of putting all the code in the preamble the way it is?